# Extending and returning values over classes

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting my values from the two sub-class.
How do I return values to Main program from the two other class? Classes have hierarchy and Cat.java extends Animal.Java. I am able to get values from the Animal class but not from the extended Cat class. What am I doing wrong?

**Main program**

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class animalProject {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to create your very own animal.");  
    System.out.println("Start by typing a name for your animal: ");
    String name = input.next();     

    Animal newAnimal = new Animal(name, 0);

    System.out.println("New Animal created");

    System.out.println("Set state of your animal: [1] Alive. [2] Dead. ");
    int status = input.nextInt();
    newAnimal.animalState(status);

    System.out.println("Print name of your animal? [1] Yes [2] No ");
    int answer = input.nextInt();
    if (answer == 1) {
        newAnimal.getName();
    }

    System.out.println("Check status of your animal? [1] Yes [2] No");
    answer = input.nextInt();
    if (answer == 1) {
        newAnimal.checkState(); 
    }

    System.out.println("Set lifes for your cat: ");
    int life = input.nextInt();
    // set lifes to lifesBefore(). in Cat.Java

    System.out.println("Remove lifes from cat?: [1] Yes [2] No");
    while (true) {
      life = input.nextInt(); {
      // call the method to decrease lifes from Cat.Java
      }
         if (life == 2){
           break;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Check cats lifes? [1] Yes [2] No");
    answer = input.nextInt();
    if (answer == 1) {
        // return lifes from Cat.java
    }
```

**Animal.Java**

```
public class Animal{

protected String name;
protected int status;


public Animal(String animalName, int animalStatus){
    name = amimalName;
    state = animalStatus;   
}

public void getName() {
    System.out.println(name);
}

public void setName() {
    this.name = name;
}

public void animalState(int status) {
    if (status == 1) {
        state = 1; // dead
    }
    else if (status == 2) {
        state = 2; // alive
    }
    else {
           System.out.println("Error with setting state.. program closing..");
           System.exit(1);
       }    
}

public void checkState() {
    if (state == 1) {
        System.out.println("Animal is dead ");
    }
    else if (state == 2) {
        System.out.println("Animal is alive");         
    }
    else {
           System.out.println("Unkown input.. program closing..");
           System.exit(1);
    }   
}
}
```

**Cat.Java**

```
public class Cat extends Animal {

private int catLifes;

public Cat(String animalName int animalStatus, int lifes) {
        super(animalName, animalStatus);
        catLifes = lifes;
    }

public void lifesBefore(){
    this.catLifes = lifes;
}


public void decreaseLifes() {

    for (int i = 0 ; i < catLifes; i++) {
        catLifes--;
    }
    System.out.println("Cat ran out of lifes and is now dead! ");
    // set animals state to dead in Animal.Java
}

public int catsLifesAfter(){
    return this.catLifes;
}
}
```

Comment: You create only objects from type `Animal`. If you want a cat you have to create a object from this type. You can do it like `Animal myCat = new Cat("Kitty", 2, 9)`

Comment: Also, it would make sense for you to make Animal abstract, so that you cannot instantiate it. Then, you need to create a Cat object, which would have access to these methods. From what I can tell, it seems like this is what you were trying to do?

Comment: Parent class reference can be used to hold child class object. But, to access child class specific methods, you need to type cast the reference to respective child class

Comment: so I need to add Animal newCat = new Cat(name, 0,9); to the main program? How am I going to set the lives then? Its confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

`Cat extends Animal` means that every `Cat`is an `Animal` but not that every `Animal` is a `Cat`.

So in your code you did create an animal using `new Animal(name, 0)`, so you got an `Animal`-object, but not a `Cat` - it could as well be a walrus.

But even using `Animal newAnimal = new Cat(name, 0,9)` you would not be able to access the `Cat`-methods. The `Animal` you created is a `Cat`, all right, but all the compiler knows about `newAnimal` is what you told it when using `Animal newAnimal` - it is an `Animal`.

So you might either say you are using a `Cat` from the beginning:

```
Cat newAnimal = new Cat(name, 0,9);
```

but then you would be losing most of the features of inheritance you want to explore. As an alternative could use a type-check and cast later on:

```
if(newAnimal instanceof Cat) {
    Cat aCat = (Cat)newAnimal;
    /*...*/
    aCat.lifesBefore()
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: I modified my code but I am still not getting it to work